# 'Property pages' tab is missing in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

On the right of VS2010, there is normally a group of tabs, like the solution explorer and the property pages tab.  It seems that the tab to access the property pages is missing.. How can I get it back?  This must be easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tabs will only appear if more than one window is docked at the same spot.  If you don't see them then you either have undocked the window or closed them.  Closing be the more likely case here, use the View menu to get them back.  Or Windows + Reset Window Layout if you're completely lost.

Comment: Reset Window layout was the trick for me. No amount of pressing F4 was bringing back my properties window.

Answer (score 5):

Click on the Project name in the Solution Explorer and then press F4. The Properties window/tab should now appear.

Note that this Properties tab is different than the one shown if you right click the project name and then click "`Properties`."

Answer (score 0):

Under View Dropdown menu, should be there.

Or right click on the app in design mode and click properties.

Answer (score 0):

Close your visual studio and open the Visual Studio Command Prompt (from window Start -> Programs -> Visual Studio XXXX -> Visual Studio XXXX Tools) and enter "devenv /setup".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dock one below the other it's a two step operation. You need to start with the two windows not connected together at all.

1) dock the first window on the right hand side of the application. This should fill all of the vertical space available.
2) make sure the second window is floating then drag it towards the first. When the arrows appear move the mouse over the down arrow and the second window should snap below the first.